# Asking username/password before updating an application - Android Market

Tags: android

I want to update my application on Google Play Store but I want to specify the users who will download it.
For example: user1 can download the new apk. But user2 can't download the newer version. Is it possible to configure such a system based on username/password  i will configure my username db such that table 1 can download the apk but table 2 can't. To do this i should ask username/password to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always download the most recent version to everyone.  Then in your app you control what features are available.  Maybe just disable the button for user1 and enable the button for user2.

As far as getting a controlling interest in google as @CommonsWare suggested you'd only need the power of a few large mutual funds to make changes and not a controlling interest.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to configure such a system based on username/password i will configure my username db such that table 1 can download the apk but table 2 can't. To do this i should ask username/password to the user.

To do that, you would need to acquire a controlling interest in Google, so you can force them to add support for your capability to the Play Store. This will cost several billion USD.

The Play Store has a beta testing capability that you are welcome to experiment with, if your objective is to temporarily make an update available to only select beta testers.

Or, you can ship your app to everyone, but only allow certain people to run it. As this will prevent other people from using the app at all, those people may get angry, and you will not like them when they are angry.

Or, you can stop shipping apps through the Play Store and distribute them yourself (e.g., through your own Web site), in which case you can do whatever you want.